# 404 not found error for assets in rails 4 production enviroment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I am new to rails from java enviroment. I have few confusions in asset pipeline with rails 3 to 4.

Currently I am in rails 4.2.5
I created a sample app on my local environment.
I created a new js from inside app/assets/javascripts and referencing it from the view , everything seems to working fine on my local environment.

After this I thought to test with production env how it works. Here are the steps I did.

1. RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clean assets:precompile [All the files created public/assets]
2. Started the server in production mode rails server -e production
3. Now when i browsed the page I am getting this error,
   `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://localhost:3000/assets/application-c5c431cb7c0a202f831a634922aaf1d536712002ae74334fb03ba4698b32b84c.js"` in firebug.

When searched few threads , they suggest to add `config.assets.compile = true`. But I do not think so this is what the solution is, as it slows down the app.

Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> By default Rails4 will return a 404 if an asset is not handled via an
>   external proxy such as Nginx.
>   - https://github.com/heroku/rails_serve_static_assets

I suggest you have a look at the [rails_12factor gem](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor), which includes the [rails_serve_static_assets gem](https://github.com/heroku/rails_serve_static_assets) which will allow your Rails app to serve static assets (like your .js file).

Edit:

You may not need a gem for this (though I've not tried it):

> `config.serve_static_files` configures Rails itself to serve static
>   files. Defaults to true, but in the production environment is turned
>   off as the server software (e.g. NGINX or Apache) used to run the
>   application should serve static assets instead. Unlike the default
>   setting set this to true when running (absolutely not recommended!) or
>   testing your app in production mode using WEBrick. Otherwise you won't
>   be able use page caching and requests for files that exist regularly
>   under the public directory will anyway hit your Rails app.
>   - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

In Rails 5, this config method has been renamed to `config.public_file_server.enabled`, the rails_serve_static_assets gem handles the correct naming depending on version.

Comment: Thanks, config.serve_static_files is working fine as per our expectation. It was quite frustrating. You saved my day.

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy If it has helped accept the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Lucas Nelson...I was fighting this some hours last night and this morning too. This was certainly helpful.
For me what I chose/worked was adding the 12factor gem.