# Deploy Devise-Rails example in production mode using Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, docker-compose, dockerfile, production-environment

I try to migrate a small rails project with the devise gem into a Docker-version. For illustration (MWE) I will use the devise-example.

Without docker everything is fine:

```sh
git clone git://github.com/RailsApps/rails-devise.git
cd rails-devise
bundle install
bundle exec rake db:migrate
rails s
```

Now I want to run this example in production inside a Docker container. Therefore, I added
 `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose.yml` and `.env.web`. The idea is to follow best-practise and put all secrets in the environment `.env.web` file, which contains all secret keys and configs:

```sh
PORT=3000
SECRET_KEY_BASE=e69d022dcead6a7025f6f7d37cf540d5c53fd5a075826998418b2165a3138ff4e32b82a45feb338a61a2d1d81f677173025b514ebc315e1fc9cd7ad4ed80d145
DOMAIN_NAME=example.com
```

The secret-key is obtained via:

```sh
bundle exec rake secret
```

To help answering this question I put everything into a fork of this repository. To reproduce my problem you can run these commands

```sh
git clone https://github.com/patwie-stuff/rails-devise.git
cd rails-devise
docker-compose build
```

works, but I got:

```sh
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
Devise.secret_key was not set. Please add the following to your Devise initializer:

  config.secret_key = '28952e4c2a1372b9ff2ec6b46fbbe942fa192fac9192982313f692e7ff3fae6c9227a8b6fd0034b87e64ebefb757c854095cc4f3594f7254280697ddf98c47b8'

Please ensure you restarted your application after installing Devise or setting the key.
/usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:475:in `raise_no_secret_key'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/devise-3.5.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:209:in `devise_for'
/myapp/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

This error results from

```sh
RUN RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
```

The default behaviour says devise uses `secret_key_base` of rails by default. This value is fetched from the environment, hence the `.env.web` file. But it is there! How can I keep the stuff from secret.yml in the environment-file.

Uncommenting line 15,16 in the Dockerfile and running

```sh
docker-compose run web ruby test.rb
```

gives the correct result `a_production_secret_key`.

Is there a **difference** between "docker-compose build" and "docker-compose run web test.rb"? Obviously, the difference is build-time and run-time.

But, how do I handle the SECRET_KEY_BASE variable for production? I do not want to hard-code this inside the Dockerfile. What is the best-practise here? For production one has to precompile the assets.

Can I put there a dummy-value for SECRET_KEY_BASE? I am not feeling good using a hard-coded dummy-value in the Dockerfile.

Comment: I'm having the same issue...though I am putting in a local env file, not env.web. Have you found an answer to this?

The only workaround I'm finding is setting the config.assets.compile = true in production, and this is definitely not best practice...

The strangest thing is that I can run rake assets:precompile within the production environment, but not on dockerfile I don't...

Answer (score 0):

After some hours and a lot of references, I finally found one that works.

What worked for me as the driest code is using solution from http://equinox.one/blog/2016/04/20/Docker-with-Ruby-on-Rails-in-development-and-production/. 
Just replace in your Dockerfile

> RUN RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace

with

```
# Set Rails to run in production
ENV RAILS_ENV production 
ENV RACK_ENV production

RUN bundle exec rake SECRET_KEY_BASE=dummytoken  assets:precompile
```

from here: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/dockerize-a-rails-5-postgres-redis-sidekiq-action-cable-app-with-docker-compose 
I understand that values before assets:precompile can be dummy, as long as they have valid syntax.

EDIT:

Though the solution above allowed me to have the assets precompiled, still the assets weren't being loaded in production.

In the end, I ended up using [rails 12 factor gem](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor), as I saw in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36441251/1461972, and it all worked out.